# how to be a delay on this script?

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript, I have no experience in coding unfortunately. So I need your help.

I'm trying to put a 10 sec delay on this code

```
document.getElementById('example').click();
```

The idea is that I want a link to be click after 10 secs.

I tried putting 10000); at the end of the code but it makes the code not work.

How can I make this code do what I want?

Comment: (found via [`[javascript] delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+delay))

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('example').click(); },10000);`

Comment: Aw, there you go it works now. Thank you very much :)